# How can i prevent duplicate form submission in PHP (that protects across multiple windows)?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have tried:

- the POST/REDIRECT/GET method, but this does not protect against multiple instances of the same form (e.g. if a user opens form.php in two separate windows, and submits the form in window 1, they can still submit in window 2)
- the UNIQUE TOKEN method, where a uid is generated into a session variable when the form is loaded and confirmed and unset when the form is processed, but if the user has other different forms open, the variable is unset from these other forms as well so they get treated as 'already processed'.

Comment: So have a unique token session for each form.

Comment: You cannot prevent this if you they the form multiple times (especially if it's different browsers)... why would they have the form open multiple times anyway?  I would just disable the submit button once it's been clicked so they can't accidentally submit the same for twice.

Comment: I've tried doing this but what happens is that if the user opens a different form it assigns a new token to the session and makes previous forms invalid

Comment: The only way I see that you can realize it is database driven. but that would need a user identification

Comment: @toby because of the nature of the datbaase transaction multiple submits can a loss of integrity so i'm trying to seal it up from all points. Your method just protects against the user pressing the submit button multiple times on the same page.

Comment: @SvenBieder unfortunately each database transaction uses a generated identification, so I am unable to check to see if it exists before i commit

Comment: How recording server-side that the form's been opened, and simply NOT serve up extra copies until the first one's cleared out? "Sorry, already open in another window". In case they 'lose' the original form, you could put in a timeout to make the exclusion period be time-limited. That'd invalidate the original form's token, and assign a new one + start new exclusion period.

Comment: @MarcB I thought about creating a session variable to record the id of the form that is currently open, and resetting to 'none' whenever it's submitted, however, what would happen if the user closes the window without submitting the form?

Comment: @StkbuhkSajsnl that'd be where the timeout period comes into play. You could try a quick little 'onwindowunload' ajax magic to try and record that the window's been closed, but that's not totally reliable.

Comment: On window unload is far too unreliable. I dabbled with that and it just wasn't anything you could count on by any standard. You could use a cookie / session design, where a javascript with a timeout could initiate an ajax "save" of current data to a cookie. On page load, check to see if any cookie data exists and load into session, continue with form.

Comment: "because of the nature of the datbaase transaction multiple submits can a loss of integrity" - How can multiple form submits lead to loss of integrity? You should have something that ensures this integrity despite the fact of having a form submitted multiple times, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the comment from user "Ofir Baruch"? It seems correct to me.

You just need to combine the two approaches you have already tried, make it correctly, and, as Ofir baruch said, have a unique token session for each form.

More or less like this:

**form1.php**

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['form_tokens']['form1']))
{
    $_SESSION['form_tokens']['form1'] = generate_random_token();
}

if (isset($_POST['token']))
{
    if ($_POST['token']) != $_SESSION['form_tokens']['form1'])
    {
        // the token is invalid - do not process the form
        redirect('/some_page');
    }
    else
    {
        // process the form here
        if ($success)
        {
            // reset the token for this form
            unset($_SESSION['form_tokens']['form1']);
            redirect('/another_page');
        }
    }
}

<form id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form_tokens']['form1']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In **form2.php** you would do the same, but using its unique token instead:

```
$_SESSION['form_tokens']['form2']
```

If you want to prevent ALSO using two different browsers - or even computers - and this is so important, then you should deal with it at another place - I mean, you should not allow that a same USER can have TWO SESSIONS. There are several ways to accomplish this, but it is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the form submissions limited to logged-in users or site visitors?

If this form is only for logged-in users, you can check their user_id as soon as the form reaches your controller.  You could set a temporary cookie or session variable while the form processes.   When the form completes, you can unset this session variable.  As soon as the form submits, check to see whether this session variable is ALREADY set (i.e. whether or not they've sent the form twice).  If this session variable is detected, fail the request.

I suppose you can do the same with site visitors, or even resort to using tables to store IP addresses, but that's a tad excessive and resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Identify which forms you want single submissions only. Then add your unique token as hidden id, for each time you generate form html and store in session. This was you know all valid IDs that are part of the unprocessed group. just one submission cancels all other IDs too of that group ONLY. this also means, when he opens few other forms after that, they start creating new group.

this open needs you to have a session array (or db) with items of all IDs that belong to unprocessed form. only one group can remain at a time. any ID not in the group is ignored/cancelled.